# Running SAS program via Crontab PuTTY

Tags: sas, cron, putty

I am new to the world of PuTTY and hoping this is an easy ask. I have 16 programs in SAS that I need to automatically kick off once a month using crontab via PuTTY environment. I have it set up to email me but it just tells me the file doesn't exist. What am I missing in my script?

```
CRONTAB:
SHELL=/bin/bash
* 9 15 * * /prod/file/sas-data2/....../SasProgram.sas
```

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

You usually need to add the SAS executable to the command.  Assuming it is in the path then just

`sas /prod/file/sas-data2/....../SasProgram.sas`

should work.

If it is not in the path, then explicitly prefix `sas` with the path.

Answer (score 1):

I find it is much easier to maintain if the CRONTAB entry points to a shell script that runs the commands.  Then if the list of SAS programs to run changes you can just edit the script file and not have to mess with CRONTAB again.

Also jobs run with CRONTAB do not normally run your normal startup file (.profile if using sh variant shells like bash) so it is useful to source those in the script so that your normal environment variables and search paths exist.

CRONTAB:

```
* 9 15 * * /mydirectory/nightly_job.ksh
```

Script file

```
#!/bin/bash
# Set environment
. /mydirectory/crontab.profile
#
cd /prod/file/sas-data2/....../
sas SasProgram.sas
```